# Anaconda navigator not launching, not even through terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I installed the latest version of Anaconda on my Windows 10. After installing i tried to launch it but it wouldn't launch even after trying several times. I also tried to launch the jupyter notebook and spider shortcut that was created but even that didn't work. So I tried to run it using the terminal and this is the error I recieved:

```
UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\capta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please take some time to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then update your question with a well-formatted [mre]. People have no idea what is causing an error if you don't explain what you where trying to do and what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem after I uninstalled the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistributable. It fixed (DLL error) after I installed Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019.

You can find it on [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)